# How to render css file from url in to the webview in android

Tags: android, html, css

I have css file url-> **http:...../test.css**.

Now  I have html string htmlString=:

```
<div class=\"detailInfo\">\r\n<table class=\"leftFloat\">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\\r\n<\/tbody>\r\n<\/table>\r\n<\/div>*
```

Then,

```
                webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewDetials);
                webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://.../css/test.css", attributes, mime, encoding, null);
```

I don't know to render above url **css** in below **htmlString** html string. any idea.

There are lots of example get css from assets folder but i cannot find load css from url.

Comment: i dont get it. so, you want to inject css into html?

Comment: Yes, i want to inject above url css in to my html.

Comment: that, some serious security leak. but, you can just change style of 1 attribute or more using webview.sendJavascript(), rather than inject css file

Comment: Look at first answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473701/how-to-apply-css-into-webview-for-remote-htmlurl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced such type of problem, May be helpful for you,

```
                webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\"http://test.com/css/test.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
                sb.append(attributes.toString());
                sb.append("</body></HTML>");
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Hopefully, it works.

related Links:

and github plugin: https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner

[Android WebView renders blank/white, view doesn't update on css changes or HTML changes, animations are choppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500452/android-webview-renders-blank-white-view-doesnt-update-on-css-changes-or-html)

Answer (score 0):

use Jsoup to cut the CSS t

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect(MyTaskParams.base_URL+MyTaskParams.sub_URL).get();
 doc.head().getElementsByTag("link").remove();
 doc.head().appendElement("link").attr("rel", "stylesheet").attr("type", "text/css").attr("href", "http://www.xyz.cm/pages/myown.css");
```

Comment: Give me some detials about **MyTaskParams.base_URL** and **MyTaskParams.sub_URL**. and what is the type of doc.